# How to set default zoom of kendo-chart in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-angular-ui

I'm trying to fix an issue I'm running into that my chart isn't letting me set the min and max of the [categoryAxis].

I've tried to bind `[categoryAxis]="{{min: 0}, {max: 12}}"` but it literally does nothing. I've also tried to see if I could figure out how to set the zoom within the ngOnInit() but I've not found a way to do that yet.

```html
<kendo-chart [pannable]="true" [zoomable]="{mousewheel: {lock: 'y'}, selection: {lock: 'y'}}" renderAs="canvas">
    <kendo-chart-title text="ChartTitle"></kendo-chart-title>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis>
                <kendo-chart-category-axis-item  [categories]="categories" 
                 [title]="{text: currentCategoryTitle}">
                </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
        </kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item [type]="'line'" [style]="'smooth'"[data]="data">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
         </kendo-chart-series>
<kendo-chart>
```

It's basically doing nothing, and I've no idea where to bind (and how to bind) the categoryAxis. I'm fairly new to kendo and their documentation is absolutely atrocious to find out what I'm meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[categoryAxis]="{min:0, max:12}"` instead.

Stackblitz:[kendo-chart-zoomable-min-max](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-kendo-chart-zoom-lock?file=app/app.component.ts)